# Magento Add to Cart not working

Tags: php, javascript, magento

"add to cart" is not working in my Magento Mobile version. Its build up of Jquery-Mobile.

Javascript console says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined

I searched the code for a long time but couldnt find out the error. I am a little bit new to magento and Jquery- mobile versions. Please help. I will share my codes below.

app/design/frontend/mobile/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-shop">
            <div class="product-name">
                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            </div>

            <?php /* @todo
            <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
             */ ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>


            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>

        </div>

        <div class="product-img-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
        </div>

        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            alert("hiii");
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
        <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
            <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
            <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $html; ?>
        </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
    <?php /* @todo
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
     */ ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

app/design/frontend/mobile/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

as you can see i have given an alert inside the javascript submit function. But it is not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try console.log(productAddToCartForm) right after this line:

```
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
```

What is the output ?
Make sure the file containing those VarienForm js classes is actually loaded in the page. Basically check the console for any potential missing JS libraries, if you havent modified anything thats possibly the reason...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the problem occurred in Internet Explorer due to the JavaScript files being merged (a setting in the admin under System -> Configuration -> Developer).